Calculating a pushforward at a point

Let $ F : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2 $ be defined by  $ F(t) = (\cos(t), \sin(t)). $ Consider the following smooth vector fields:
$ X = \frac{d}{dt} \quad \text{and} \quad Y = x - y
 \frac{\partial}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial}{\partial x} $ defined
on $ \mathbb{R} $ and $ \mathbb{R}^2 $, respectively. Show that $
 X $ and $ Y $ are $ F $-related.

Proof
The map $ F(t) = (\cos t, \sin t) $ has the Jacobian (derivative matrix) at $ t $ given by:
\begin{equation}
    dF = \begin{pmatrix}
       -\sin t \\ \cos t 
    \end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
To show that $ X $ and $ Y $ are $ F $-related, we need to verify that:
$
Y\left(F_*(v)\right) = F_*\left(X(v)\right),
$
where $ F_* $ denotes the pushforward.
First, compute the pushforward of $ X = \frac{d}{dt} $ under $ F $:
\begin{equation}
    F_*\left(\frac{d}{dt}\right) = \frac{d}{dt} (\cos t, \sin t) = (-\sin t, \cos t).
\end{equation}
Now, apply the vector field $ Y = x \frac{\partial}{\partial y} - y \frac{\partial}{\partial x} $ at the point $ F(t) = (\cos t, \sin t) $:
\begin{equation}
    Y\left(F(t)\right) = \cos t \frac{\partial}{\partial y} - \sin t \frac{\partial}{\partial x}.
\end{equation}
Finally, evaluate $ Y $ at the vector $ (-\sin t, \cos t) $ (the result of the pushforward):
\begin{equation}
    Y\left(F_*(v)\right) = \left(\cos t \frac{\partial}{\partial y} - \sin t \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)(-\sin t, \cos t) = ?
\end{equation}
What is the last equation resulting to?
Thanks

That equation you are aiming to verify seems weird. I think you probably messed up with notations

In general let $M$ and $N$ be manifolds and let $F:M\rightarrow N$ be a smooth map. A vector field $X$ on $M$ and a vector field $Y$ on $N$ are said to be $F$-related if
$$dF_p(X_p)=Y_{F(p)},\qquad\forall p\in M$$
In your case $M=\mathbb R$, $N=\mathbb R^2$, $F(t)=(\cos t,\sin t)$ and $X=\frac{d}{dt}$, $Y = x \frac{\partial}{\partial y} - y \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ (I suppose there's a typo in your first definition of the vector field $Y$). As you correctly have calculated
$$dF_t= \begin{bmatrix}
-\sin t \\ \cos t
\end{bmatrix}$$
for all $t\in \mathbb R$. Since $t$ denotes the usual canonical coordinates on $\mathbb R$, by definition
$$dF_t(X_t)=\begin{bmatrix}
-\sin t \\ \cos t
\end{bmatrix}[1]=\begin{bmatrix}
-\sin t \\ \cos t
\end{bmatrix}$$
While in coordinates
$$Y_{F(t)}=\begin{bmatrix}
-y \\ x
\end{bmatrix}_{(\cos t,\sin t)}=\begin{bmatrix}
-\sin t \\ \cos t
\end{bmatrix}$$
Thus we have shown that
$$dF_t(X_t)=Y_{F(t)},\qquad \forall t\in \mathbb R$$
i.e. that the two vector fields are $F$-related.

Details. The the canonical coordinates $t$ on $\mathbb R$ and $x,y$ on $\mathbb R^2$ induce coordinates on the tangent spaces: $\frac{d}{dt}$ on $T_t\mathbb R$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ on $T_{(x,y)}\mathbb R^2$. So, in these coordinates on the tangent spaces, $X_t$ has component equal to $1$ (since $X$ is constantly equal to $\frac{d}{dt}$), which is the $[1]$ you asked me for clarifications, while $Y=-y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ has components equal to $[-y,x]^T$ (here $^T$ denotes the transpose of the vector).

Thanks, but why that [1] ?

@Superunknown I've added some more details in the answer. Let me know if this helps.

I do this by applying the Proposition 8.16 of the book GTM218 "Intro to smooth manifolds" written by John Lee.
Pick an arbitrary smooth function $f\colon \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$, say with coordinates $(x,y)$. Then $f\circ F = f(\cos t, \sin t)$, and
$$
X(f\circ F) = \frac  {\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} f(\cos t, \sin t) = -\sin t \partial_x f (\cos t, \sin t) + \cos t  \partial_y f(\cos t, \sin t), 
$$
meanwhile
$$
(Yf)\circ F = (x \partial_y f - y\partial_x f) \circ F = (x \partial_y f(x,y) - y\partial_x f(x,y))\Biggr\vert_{(x,y)= (\cos t , \sin t)} = \cos t \partial_2 f(\cos t, \sin t) - \sin t \partial_1 f(\cos t  , \sin t),
$$
which means the equation $X(f\circ F) = (Yf)\circ F$ is true. Hence $X, Y$ are $F$-related.
The proposition is

Suppose $F \colon M \to N$ is a smooth map between manifolds with/out boundary, $X \in \mathfrak X(M), Y \in \mathfrak X(N)$. Then $X,Y$ are $F$-related iff for every smooth real-valued function $f$ defined on an open subset of $N$, $$ X(f\circ F) = (Yf)\circ F. $$

